# Form Response Not Emailing

Tags: php, forms

I have a form that's not emailing the response and I can't figure out why. Anything in the '$__' doesn't seem to be pulling correctly. It's just blank in my email. It is a multi-page form (2 pages) so i'm wondering it that's the problem and i'm missing something for that?

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<form name="firstForm" id="firstForm" action="submit.php" method="POST" enctype="">   

                       <div class="field"> <span class="fieldItem text">
                        <input autocomplete="off" placeholder="Address" id="address" name="address" type="text">
                        </span> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col cols6 lastCol plm">
                      <div class="field"> <span class="fieldItem text">
                        <input name="unitnumber" id="unitnumber" placeholder="Unit #" type="text">
                        </span> </div>
                    </div>

                        <select style="width: 108px; position: absolute; opacity: 0; height: 36px; font-size: 14px;" id="state" name="state" class="styled sidebr01 hasCustomSelect">
                          <option selected="selected" value="-10">State</option>
                          <option value="AL">AL</option>
                         </select><span style="display: inline-block;" class="customSelect styled sidebr01"><span style="display: inline-block;" class="customSelectInner">State</span></span>
                        <div class="tobeSelectDisplay btn btnDefault"> <span class="selectLabel typeLowlight">State</span> <span class="selectTrigger typeLowlight"><i class="iconDownOpen"></i></span> </div>
                        </span> </span> </div>
                    </div>

                      <div class="field"> <span class="fieldItem text">
                        <input name="zip" placeholder="Zip" id="zip" type="text">


                  <a href="#" onClick="ValiDate();" class="mln typeDeemphasize btn btnPrimary btnLrg">Get a Personalized Report</a>
                  <noscript>

                  <div class="form_error hideFully box alert alertWarn mhs">
                    <div class="boxBody">
                      <p class="typeContrast mvm txtL"></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  </noscript>


                               <label class="fieldLabel" for="ValuationInquiry[Full_Name]">Full Name</label>
                        <span class="fieldItem text">
                        <input placeholder="John Smith" name="full_name" id="full_name" type="text">
                        </span> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col cols12 lastCol"></div>

        <div class="col cols12">
          <div class="field">
            <label class="fieldLabel" for="ValuationInquiry[Last_Name]">Last Name</label>
            <span class="fieldItem text">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Smith"  name="last_name" id="last_name">
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col cols12 lastCol"></div>
      </div>-->
                  <div class="line pvm2">
                      <div class="field">
                        <label class="fieldLabel" for="ValuationInquiry[Email_Address]">Email Address</label>
                        <span class="fieldItem text">
                        <input placeholder="johnsmith@example.com" name="email_address" id="email_address" type="email">
                        </span> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col cols12 lastCol"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="line ptm2">
                      <div class="field">
                        <label class="fieldLabel" for="ValuationInquiry[Phone]">Phone Number</label>
                        <span class="fieldItem text">
                        <input title="10-digit US Phone Number" name="phone" id="phone" type="text">
                        </span> </div>
                    <div class="col cols12 lastCol"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                    <input value="steptwo" name="skipsecondstep" type="hidden">
                    <input value="Get Your Full Report" id="required_form_cta" class="typeDeemphasize btn btnPrimary" onClick="lastvalidate();" type="button">


    <!--</form>--> 
  </div>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php


$email_from = 'email@email.com';//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "Entry Received";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $full_name.\n".
    "Zip Code:\n $zip".


$to = "email@email.com";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_address \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: submit.html');


// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never assign values to `$full_name` and `$zip`. They don't magically populate with values from your form.<sup>1</sup> You have to assign those values yourself:

```
$full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
$zip = $_POST['zip'];
$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $full_name.\n".
"Zip Code:\n $zip".
```

<sup>1</sup> PHP used to have a feature called `register_globals` which was on by default that *would* populate variables from forms automatically. But this feature was deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0 and removed as of PHP 5.4.0.

Comment: Ah, that's what I was missing. Will try that now, thank you. Not a pro on forms (as you can see)!